# From Typescript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a ts code that was translated in js and now i want to use instantiate objects from the generated js code but i am having the error "object" not defined.

For example the class in ts look like this:

```
class Person{
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string){
        this.name = name;
  }
/*...*/
}
```

And the generated js:

```
class Person{    
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
  }
/*...*/
}
```

now to used the object `Person` i did something like this:

```
var bob = new Person("bob");
```

But i am getting the error: *Person is not defined*.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

var bob = new Person("bob");

console.log(bob);
```

Comment: `var bob = new Person("bob");`

Comment: @connexo this will not fix the `Person is not defined.` error.

Comment: sorry even with new nothing works

Comment: DerMann, are both class and the code `Person("bob")` located in one file? If not, how do you import/require the class?

Comment: `class Person() {` has to be `class Person {`.

Comment: no. there are just in the same folder

Comment: DerMann, I am not asking if they are in one folder, I am asking if they are in one file. BTW @connexo is right, your class declaration is malformed.

Comment: There are in seprated files. And i have corrected all the stupid errors

Comment: Then in your file where you have `class Person { ... }`, as the last line in that file add `window.Person = Person;`. Otherwise `Person` stays scoped to the file where you define the class.

Answer (score 1):

So your class declaration and the code that references it are in different files (from your comments).

Hence, you should require the class to use it like this:

```
const Person = require('./Person.js')
```

And in the file with the class declaration you should export it like this (in the end):

```
module.exports = Person
```

The above is [node module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) syntax. Google "browser modules" if you work on browser code.

But the real question: Why you work on `.js` files when you have `.ts` ones? With TS you could use [modern modules syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). And it would work in browser or in node, if your TS configured properly.